# Xcode 5 indentation issue

Tags: ios, xcode, formatting, indentation

I get indentation issues when I copy few lines and paste it. Xcode does not copy indentation properly or applies another indentations.

As shown in below images, I copied first function and pasted which is second function. Indentation are reapplied except for first line.

[image]

I played with Xcode indentation settings but could not solve it neither do I have any clue why this happens.

Below are 2 indentation settings I tried.

[image]

[image]

Do anybody see anything wrong in above settings?

Comment: do you simply paste with command-V (plain ol' paste) or do you use the paste-and-preserve-formatting Xcode edit menu choice (which has a crazy key combination including command-V)??

Comment: @MichaelDautermann I use command-V.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I just checked Xcode settings in another mac and made changes to match that and solved the issue. Sorry I don't remember what were they as it has been too long.

Answer (score 6):

In Xcode preferences, Key Bindings tab, redefine ⌘-V to "Paste and Preserve Formatting" and ⌘-option-shift-V to "Paste". Then ⌘-V will do "Paste and Preserve Formatting" which is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off Auto-Indentation. That way, Xcode doesn't remove formatting.

Answer (score 0):

That was when i customized indentation in Swift and then get back to Obj-C. Nothing with changing preferences helped. Just fully restart xcode.

Answer (score -1):

With cut and paste, you have to actually tell xcode to indent after the pasting.

⌘ A and then Control I.
The first one select the whole class contents (when the cursor is inside) and the second one indents it based on your indent preferences.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This added unnecessary indents to almost all lines in a class.

Comment: This will do whatever you set your indentation setting to be. So if you change "indent width" to 3 spaces and then repeat, it will change indentation to 3 spaces. Alternatively ⌘ z to undo and only select the code you want to indent and then Control I.

Comment: I don't want that indents added when pasting the code. Those are unnecessary. I want it to paste exactly same as what I copied.

Comment: Then I would use @MichaelDautermann answer when pasting: Edit + "paste and preserve formatting"

Comment: I don't want to use that as it involves pressing 4 keys at a time. And till today command-v used to work in Xcode5.

Comment: If someone is going to downvote 3 of my answers randomly, 3 months after posting; at a minimum, please post a comment with the reason (if there is one).